# Checking if regular expressions are equivalent

Tags: regular-expressions

Is there a quick script/tool to check if two regular expressions are equal? For example: I want to know if `0*(01 + 11)` is equal to `(0*01 + 0*11)` i.e. Can I multiply them just as basic math?

Comment: Yes, these two are equivalent, and yes, $\sigma(\tau+\rho)=\sigma\tau+\sigma\rho$ for regular expressions $\sigma,\tau,\rho$. There is an algebra of regular expressions; some of it, like the bit that you used here, is very straightforward. Dealing with the Kleene star can get a little more complicated, however.

Comment: For arbitrary regexes, the idea is to first convert each to a DFA: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12267/algorithm-to-determine-whether-two-regexes-are-equivalent